# Angular 8 - clean localStroage generated by iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

Hi I am working on a project (say projectA) with Angular 8 that has an iframe that loads another website (say projectB). The website in iframe is also written in Angular 8 with ngrx and ngrx state is saved in localStorage.

When I unload the iframe from projectA by redirect to another page, I assume prjectB is destoryed and the data saved in localStorage should be removed.

I print a message in onDestroy in projectB but it is not shown in console. And when I load the iframe again, I found  the state is restored.

Is there anyway I can clean localStorage when the iframe is unloaded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try using the document (application) load/unload events in individual frame app to clean the localstorage e.g.

```
document.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.clear(); 
  return '';
};
OR
document.load = function() {
      localStorage.clear(); 
      return '';
    };
```

Alternately, register a window level even listener when frameset loads and fire the required even/customevent from individual app on using ngOnInit() e.g

```
 window.addEventListener('load',  function() {
      localStorage.clear(); 
      return '';
    };
  )
```